# Comparing objects before and after some events in java in printed texts

Tags: java

I need a solution to the following problem. Suppose I have different fields in a class. Each of different type, some may be basic types such as Integers, some may be complex object type fields. I need to find a way to compare those fields after exit and restart of the app. By I am limited to dumping the values to file and comparing those. How can I put something on file and compare them so that I can determine whether they have changed or not. I do not need the values. Will `getHashCode()` help?

Comment: Are you re-reading the file to restore your state before the program closed?

Comment: yes. Like I am dumping the contents and after restart I am comparing them. my question is how to dump to best describe the Value properties.

Comment: I am not comparing the file contents. I am concerned about what should I put on the file to compare, because some values may be objects. So I need a representation.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand  your question, you would like to compare content in a file after exit and before restart. One way would be to use a message digest. As in calculating the SHA1 of the contents and comparing that before restart.

Comment: To put it in a simpler way what will be the best printable form of the value properties of the fields. Like an unified printable data independent of the data types. Just to compute the differences.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like [Java object serialization](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/objects/serial.html) might do the trick for you. With serialization, you can write any object to a file, and later read it in again and reconstruct the original object. If you then have an isEqual() method on the object, you can use that to simply check whether the object is the same.

EDIT: reread the question. If you want to compare the file contents, then serialization is not particular useful, as there are bound to be small differences between the two files.

Answer (score 0):

I guess `hashCode()` will help only if it's implemented in such a way that will return the same result for two objects if the objects have the same values. Of course, for non-primitive fields you'll have to decide what does "same value" mean, and you would be probably required to implement `hashCode()` for the types of those fields as well.

If you can't/don't want to implement `hashCode()` maybe JSON could help. I suggest using a library like Google's [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) to render a string representation of your object which you can then dump to file. If the way in which the object (or any of its members) is converted to string does not suit your needs you can specify the conversion with a `JsonSerializer`.

```
String strRep = new Gson().toJson(myObject);
```

Comment: Are you meaning that transforming all the objects in Json format which inturn transform field objects to json in a nested way until primitive values remains and dump them to file?

Comment: @Pbasak Yes. Object to JSON conversion as provided by Gson recursively converts all field objects, field objects of field objects, etc. unless you specify otherwise, and builds the corresponding JSON tree. I guess cyclic references may need special treatment, though.